# jQuery - Open div onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs, which from I'd like the first one to be expanded from default.

### Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.infoexpanderHead').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
    $(this).find('#infoactive').addClass("active");
    $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideDown();
    $(this).siblings().find('#infoactive').removeClass("active");
});
```

### What I've tried

```
function onload(){
    $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
}
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4SWnm/

Comment: What is not working with your current code?

Comment: You shouldn't use `$(this).find('#someId')` since you can access the object with `$('#someId')` (much more efficient). Or is it that you just want to remove the class if it's a sibling of your `.expanderHead`? By the way, I would do `var $this = $(this)` in your second line of code, to avoid constructing the object 4 times

Comment: @David open div OnLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the click event for the list `infoexpanderHead` element after the handler is registered

```
$('.infoexpanderHead').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
    $(this).find('#infoactive').addClass("active");
    $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideDown();
    $(this).siblings().find('#infoactive').removeClass("active");
}).first().click();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N7QGK/)

Answer (score 0):

insted of onload function you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
});
```

or if you want to use onload function

try like this at the end of file call function

```
onload();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the click event for first element.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4SWnm/2/)**

```
    $('.infoexpanderHead').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().find('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp();
        $(this).find('#infoactive').addClass("active");
        $(this).find('.infoexpanderContent').slideDown();
                 $(this).siblings().find('#infoactive').removeClass("active");
    });
    var frstdiv=$('.infoexpanderHead')[0];
    $(frstdiv).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `slideup` `div` works fine, but the `div` is hidden, so you have to show that `div` by using jQuery show method. Try this code, it works for me.

### Code

---

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   $('.infoexpanderContent').slideUp().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the first infoexpanderHead element's infoexpanderContent, and slide it down when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".infoexpanderHead").first().find(".infoexpanderContent").slideDown();
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/258Vz/